# User registration flow UML diagrams

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

This my first UML diagram for user registration flow.

After double checking the diagram I feel that I have a crowded diagram compared to what I can found in Google search.

My questions:

Are my `alt and else` branches usage correct?

Is it valid to include error responses in the sequence diagrams?

Is it valid to include the notes I have included?

Here is my Sequence Diagram design:

[image]

And here is my Sequence Diagram code:

```
@startuml

actor Client
participant Controller
participant UserRepository
participant UserProfileRepository
database MongoDB

Client -> Controller ++ : Registration Request
note left
Http Method: POST
Token Type: CREDENTIALS
Token: EMAIL:PASSWORD
end note

Controller -> Controller : Validate token type,\nemail, password\nand email not already\nused

alt if all are valid
Controller -> UserRepository ++ : Create new user
UserRepository -> MongoDB : Save created\nuser in DB
UserRepository -> Controller -- : Return created user

Controller -> UserProfileRepository ++ : Create new user profile
UserProfileRepository -> MongoDB : Save created user\nprofile in DB
UserProfileRepository -> Controller -- : Return created user profile

Controller -> Client : Return user id
note left
Http Status : 201 Created
User id returned in Header
Location: /users/USER_ID,/usersProfiles/USER_ID
end note
else if invalid token
Controller -> Client : invalid request
note left
Http Status : 400 Bad Request
end note
else if invalid email
Controller -> Client : invalid email
note left
Http Status : 400 Bad Request
end note
else if invalid password
Controller -> Client : invalid invalid password
note left
Http Status : 400 Bad Request
end note
else if email already used
Controller -> Client -- : user already exist
note left
Http Status : 409 Conflict
end note
end

@enduml
```

Comment: StartUML has a couple of flaws. One of them are arrows (in general). Above is a mixture of a/synch. They are half open/filled. Sync is a filled triangle, asynch an open arrow.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to ask the most important thing: can my diagram be understood?
Fortunately, the answer to that is: Yes, it is perfectly well understandable.

For the questions you did ask, the answer is also to all of them that it is correct.

There are some things that I would have done differently or not entirely correct in the diagram, but I am not sure in how far that is due to a limitation in the tool you use.

- The return arrows from a function call should be dashed arrows with an open arrowhead, like this `- ->`. They are typically only given a label when the return value is not obvious from how the call is made.
- Personally, I would have used the HTTP status code as label on the corresponding arrow, rather than mentioning it in a separate note. The fact that you are using HTTP is already clear from the note on the initial request message.

Comment: _return arrows from a function call **should** be dashed_ no. It's **must**.